# How to dual boot Windows from Linux without USB or CD?

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot

I am on Linux Mint and I want to dual boot with Windows, how can I create a new partition and have Windows 7 installed on it?

Comment: i can't see how it can be done when you can't boot machine from windows installer (so - USB/CD/DVD etc). you can install win7 on some virtual machine in this case.

Answer (score -1):

<s>You can use an SD Card.</s> Ok I have had my fun here is the real answer.

Simply put, It is impossible. You need something to install off of. E.G. A USB/SD/CD.

Here is a guide this is for installing MINT but you should be able to adapt the guide to what you need to do.

http://www.pcworld.com/article/2955460/operating-systems/dual-booting-linux-with-windows-what-you-need-to-know.html

You also could use virtualbox.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your post, to better answer his question?  Perhaps offer a guide on how to setup a dual boot computer?